# Sum columns of R data table, the names of which are stored in a vector

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table:

```
dt_test <- data.table(day = 1:3, a = c(1,1,1), b = c(2,2,2))

     day  a b
1:   1    1 2
2:   2    1 2
3:   3    1 2
```

Also, I have a vector with the columns I want to add:

```
vecCols <- c("a", "b")
```

I would like to have a new column `sums` in my data table, which in this case is just `sums := a + b`, or a sum over all the columns in vecCols (input from vecCols may vary in different situations, it is dynamically filled)

The output in this example case should look like this:

```
     day  a b sums
1:   1    1 2    3
2:   2    1 2    3
3:   3    1 2    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` on the relevant subset :

```
dt_test <- data.table::data.table(day = 1:3, a = c(1,1,1), b = c(2,2,2))
vecCols <- c("a", "b")

dt_test[,sums := rowSums(.SD[,vecCols, with = FALSE])]
```

or

```
dt_test[,sums := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = vecCols]

dt_test
#>    day a b sums
#> 1:   1 1 2    3
#> 2:   2 1 2    3
#> 3:   3 1 2    3
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

You could use dplyr:

```
dt_test %>% 
  mutate(Sum = rowSums(select(., matches(paste0(vecCols, collapse = "|")), -day)))
```